# For Loop Copy and Paste Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Function Iterate()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 10
Worksheets("Calculator").Calculate
Worksheets("Calculator").Range("AC6:AC16").Copy  Destination:=Sheets("Iterations").Range("A1:A10")
Worksheets("Calculator").Range("AT10:AT11").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Iterationas").Range("A11:A12")
                         Worksheets("Iterations").Paste

Next

End Function
```

My Goal, is to run this loop as many times as I'll need, and after every single loop, I want excel to take the Range("cells") and copy them to the "Iterations" worksheet.

The data on Calculator is refreshed every loop, so new calculations appear. Once the new calculations appear, I want to paste it one next to the other (which I don't know how to do).

For now, this gives me a runtime error Subscript it out of range

Any advice?

Comment: are AC6, AC16 variables? if so, how are they defined? if not, they need to be in quotes... and use a colon instead of a comma... where are you learning this code? it makes no sense

Comment: I'm trying to pick it up as fast as I can.. 
I'm more familiar with Python Syntax

and every loop, AC6,AC16 are changing because of randbetween() function

Comment: a range definition needs to look more like this `Worksheets("Calculator").Range("AC6:AC16")`

Comment: Yeah, I changed it, and now I'm at the Runtime Error, Subscript out of range.

would you know how I would be able to paste the data at a column one after the other?

Comment: changed it to what? are you expecting people to read your mind? update your post as you go so people can see what you did.

Comment: Changed the code, with your recommendation's and changed the code above.

Comment: in this case 'subscript out of range' typically means that there is no worksheet called "Calculator" in your workbook.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Iterate()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 10
        Worksheets(1).Calculate
        Worksheets(1).Range("AC6:AC16").Copy Destination:=Worksheets(2).Range("A1:A10")
        Worksheets(1).Range("AT10:AT11").Copy Destination:=Worksheets(2).Range("A11:A12")
    Next

End Sub
```

It works, just make sure that you rename the Worksheets(1) and (2) relevantly. In general, use `Function`, when you expect a value to be returned. For changes in a worksheet, use `Sub`.

In general, what you wanted in the comments is to copy the values and to put them next to each other column. Here is how to get it:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Iterate()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 10
        With Worksheets(1)

        Worksheets(2).Calculate

        Worksheets(2).Range("AC6:AC16").Copy
        .Cells(1, i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        Worksheets(2).Range("AT10:AT11").Copy
        .Cells(1, i + 10).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you..

In order for me to paste special should I just write PasteSpecial:= (after each worksheet)??
and then the social paste I want?

Comment: And the reason I have this loop, comes from the fact that every refresh, the excel page generate new numbers that make a different calculations. 

That is why I wanted to Paste the SpecialValues, and after I run this 10 times the calculations will show up in the other sheet one column next to the other.

Comment: @YoavPoni - I think I got what you want. See the edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! @Vityata

Comment: is there a reason for the Excel file to go wrong when the I execute the Macro?

Comment: @YoavPoni - idk, if it goes wrong there should be a reason for this... E.g. Worksheets are protected, there are other macros or anything else...